# Getting PowerMockito to mock a static method on an Interface?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, powermockito

I have a library I am trying to mock for testing... There is a Java 8 interface with a static method implementation like this:

```
public interface Router {
    public static Router router(Object param) {
        return new RouterImpl(param);
    }
}
```

And I am trying to mock that returned value:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Router.class);
PowerMockito.doReturn(mockRouter).when(Router.router(any()));
```

But when I run the tests through a debugger, the mock instance is not returned.

I've tried a number of different permutations of the static mocking, but I cannot get the static method to return my mock value. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it right, but we will have to wait when mocking static interface method is implemented/fixed in PowerMock. Watch this pull request: 
https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/510

Note: Good news is that issue in Javassist is already fixed:

https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/pull/11

Comment: Looks like PowerMock 1.6.5 adds support for it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not wrap it in an abstraction that you can mock?

```
class RouterFactory {

    Router createRouter(Object param) {
        return Router.router(param);
    }
}
```

And use it in your class

```
class YourClass {
private final RouterFactory routerFactory;

YourClass(RouterFactory routerFactory) {
this.routerFactory = routerFactory;
}

void doSth() {
   // do sth    
}

}
```

Then you can mock the RouterFactory without any problems and you don't have to use Powermock.